# How to fix "timeout: _ssl.c:1039: The handshake operation timed out"

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

I am attempting to use the Google Analytics API and I am getting a timeout error. I do not know how to fix this issue.

```
def initialize_analyticsreporting():

    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

    analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4',credentials=credentials)

    return analytics

def get_report(analytics):

    return analytics.reports().batchGet(
  body={
    'reportRequests': [
    {
      'viewId': VIEW_ID,
      'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
      'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'}],
      'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:country'}]
    }]
  }).execute()

def print_response(response):

   for report in response.get('reports', []):
    columnHeader = report.get('columnHeader', {})
    dimensionHeaders = columnHeader.get('dimensions', [])
    metricHeaders = columnHeader.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])

    for row in report.get('data', {}).get('rows', []):
        dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
        dateRangeValues = row.get('metrics', [])

        for header, dimension in zip(dimensionHeaders, dimensions):
            print(header + ': ' + dimension)

            for i, values in enumerate(dateRangeValues):
                print('Date range: ' + str(i))
                for metricHeader, value in zip(metricHeaders, values.get('values')):
                    print(metricHeader.get('name') + ': ' + value)


def main():
    analytics = initialize_analyticsreporting()
    response = get_report(analytics)
    print_response(response)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expect the output to be a dataframe with the data I have requested but instead I get the the error "timeout: _ssl.c:1039: The handshake operation timed out"

Comment: Hello! might I ask have you solved it? And how?

Comment: I've had the same problem, no luck.